# Any performance implications when using "__global const" on a large buffer?

Tags: opencl

I have a GPU application (running on AMD Radeon Pro cards) that involves processing data across several stages, where each kernel reads data from one buffer and writes the processed values to another buffer, which will be used as input to the next kernel. The buffers are created using the `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` flag, while in the individual kernels I use the `const` keyword on the "input" buffer's argument, which I always thought was little more than a compiler hint to indicate that the buffer is read-only.

I've since discovered that there is more to it than this, with a dedicated area of device memory allocated as "constant" memory, which is apparently quite small (64Kb?) whereas my buffers are hundreds of Mb in size. I believe OpenCL will fill constant memory from the buffer, but revert to global memory once constant memory is full. Does this mean there could be a performance penalty in using the `const` keyword on my large buffer arguments?

Comment: If anything, I would expect it to be quicker or the same with the const keyword. Why not try benchmarking your application with and without them... Your global memory cache will also be too small to fit your buffers into so if you're doing lots of random access, you could be getting a lot of cache misses. Some high end CPUs have hundreds of MB of cache, so for random accesses it might be worth looking at running your application on a CPU with say 768MB of cache for better performance than any GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` keyword has no effects on performance. It is merely a hint to the programmer that the variable/parameter cannot be modified and has to be accessed read-only. This in turn makes it very useful to avoid accidentally modifying such a variable/parameter, as the compiler will throw an error.

The `constant` keyword in OpenCL is entirely different from `const`. `constant` refers to a separate region in the OpenCL memory model, hinting the compiler to place the array in L2/L3 cache if it is small enough, or in VRAM otherwise. `constant` should be used for lookup-tables for example, which can also be placed in the OpenCL code outside of kernels where you would place global variables in a C++ program.

There is also the `restrict` keyword which may be used to hint the compiler that several kernel parameters/arrays in `global` memory do not alias (overlap).

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. I hadn't realised that "const" and "constant" were separate keywords. That makes sense then.

Comment: Some devices have dedicated cache for constant memory other than L1/L2. Constant memory is fastest when all work items lookup for same index at the same time. Amd's opencl document said its as fast as accessing registers or 4 bytes per cycle per shader for southern islands architecture. This is like 8 terabytes per second for 2048 shaders at 1GHz.